# Vim highlighting sometimes requires a kickstart?

Tags: vim

Centos 6, vim 7.2.411, my .vimrc file:

```
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *.html set filetype=php
set tabstop=4
set shiftwidth=4
set nowrap
set autoindent
set number
if has('mouse')
  set mouse=a
endif
set backspace=start,indent,eol
set t_Co=256
colorscheme molokai
```

(Although I code in php I save my files as .html - a bad practice I imagine?  But something I started in this project years ago when I thought I was being clever - security through obscurity etc, and I don't have the time/inclination to change it now)

Generally the colorscheming works, but sometimes I'll load a file and it'll be out of whack, like there's an unclosed string somewhere or similar.  Scrolling up and back down tends to fix it, though sometimes I need to go into insert mode and add a newline for it to "wake up".

How can I fix this?

Comment: The "wrong" file extension shouldn't matter here, as you're reconfiguring the filetype detection to handle this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The PHP syntax plugin allows to configure this; cp. `:help ft-php-syntax`:

> Selecting syncing method:
>
> ```
> let php_sync_method = x
> ```
>
> x = -1 to sync by search (default),
>   x > 0 to sync at least x lines backwards,
>   x = 0 to sync from start.

The different sync options are documented under `:help :syn-sync`. You have to understand that this always is a trade-off between correctness (`:let php_sync_method = 0`) and performance. Experiment with different values, and decide for yourself with what amount of delay / manual refreshes you can live with.

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you.  I asked the same thing ages ago and got no answers, but this is spot on.  The files I work on are rarely more than 1000 lines so I've set it to 0.